# What is the meaning of "whom I serve from my forefathers" in 2 Timothy 1:3?

Tags: kjv, 2-timothy

> I thank God, **whom I serve from my forefathers** with pure conscience, that without ceasing I have remembrance of thee in my prayers night and day; *(2 Timothy 1:3, KJV)* (Emphasis added)

What does "whom I serve from my forefathers" mean?

I want to also know:

1. Is Paul taking credit for how his forefathers worshipped God?
2. Should not the reverse be true? I mean parents taking credit for child's success seems logical to me instead of children taking credit for parent's success

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE, I made a slight edit to remove a portion of the question that is off topic here (searching for a text). We stick to specific texts and explaining them in their original historical, linguistic, and literary setting(s). This is an interesting question, glad to have you!

Comment: Children constantly base their identity and worth on their parents through heredity and inheritance, especially in the Bible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Greek text of 2 Tim. 1:3 according to Robert Estienne’s Textus Receptus (1550) states,

[image: 2 Timothy 1:3 in Robert Estienne's Textus Receptus, 1550]

> Χάριν ἔχω τῷ θεῷ ᾧ λατρεύω ἀπὸ προγόνων ἐν καθαρᾷ συνειδήσει ὡς ἀδιάλειπτον ἔχω τὴν περὶ σοῦ μνείαν ἐν ταῖς δεήσεσίν μου νυκτὸς καὶ ἡμέρας

On the Greek word πρόγονος, Christian Gottlob Wilke (translated by Joseph Henry Thayer) wrote,<sup>1</sup>

> πρό-γονος, -ου, ὁ, (προγίνομαι), born before, older: Hom. Od. 9, 221; plur. ancestors, Lat. majores, (often so by Grk. writ. fr. Pind. down): **ἀπὸ προγόνων, in the spirit and after the manner received from (my) forefathers** [cf. ἀπό, II. 2 d. aa. p. 59 bot.], 2 Tim. 1:3; used of a mother, grandparents, and (if such survive) great-grandparents, 1 Tim. 5:4 [A. V. parents] (of surviving ancestors also in Plato, legg. 11 p. 932 init.).*

Wilke references his entry on the preposition ἀπό (II. 2 d. aa.):<sup>2</sup>

> II. of Origin; whether of local origin, the place whence; or of causa origin, the cause from which.
>
> 2 of causal origin, or the Cause; and
>
> d. of the efficient cause, viz. of things from the force of which anything proceeds, and of persons from whose will, power, authority, command, favor, order, influence, direction, anything is to be sought;
>
> aa. in general: ...λατρεύω τῷ θεῷ ἀπὸ προγόνων **after the manner of the λατρεία received from my forefathers** [cf. W. 372 (349); B. 322 (277)], 2 Tim. 1:3.

Thayer cites other authorities, including Winer and Buttman.

Winer writes,<sup>3</sup> <sup>4</sup>

[image: Winer, A Grammar of the Idiom of the New Testament, ἀπό, p. 372]

Buttman wrote,<sup>5</sup>

[image: Buttman, A Grammar of the New Testament Greek, p. 322]

Who are the πρόγονοι to whom the apostle Paul refers? Some might believe that he is speaking of the patriarchs, such as Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, as he calls Abraham “our father” (ὁ πατήρ ἡμῶν cp. Rom. 4:12). While πατήρ is not identical to πρόγονος, it's not out of the realm of possibility. Another possibility, however, is that the apostle Paul would be referring to his immediate ancestors in the same way that he mentions Timothy”s immediate ancestors, his mother Eunice and grandmother Lois (2 Tim. 1:5).

> 1.Is Paul taking credit for how his forefathers worshipped God?
>
> 2.Should not the reverse be true (i.e., parents taking credit for child’s success seems logical to me instead of children taking credit for parent’s success)?

The apostle Paul is not taking credit for their worship, after all, how could **he** who was born **after** them have influenced **their** worship? Rather, the apostle Paul is simply saying that his ancestors also worshipped God in the same manner as himself. That is, they too were Jews. The apostle Paul did not see himself as an adherent of a new religion, but one who continued in “the way” (ἡ ὁδός) of his ancestors (Acts 24:14). Judaism (ὁ Ἰουδαϊσμός cp. Gal. 1:13) was not a human contrivance but the true form of worship in the apostle Paul’s eyes. He confessed, “I am a Pharisee, the son of a Pharisee...” (Acts 23:6) and “I am a man, a Jew...brought up in this city at the feet of Gamaliel, and taught according to the perfect manner of the paternal law (τοῦ πατρῴου νόμου), being zealous toward God, just as you all are today” (Acts 22:3).

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> p. [538](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA538#v=onepage&q&f=true)
<sup>2</sup> p. [59](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA59#v=onepage&q&f=true)
<sup>3</sup> p. [372](https://books.google.com/books?id=IE5CAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA372#v=onepage&q&f=true), §4
<sup>4</sup> The Latin word *modo* means “manner,” and the word *instar* means “resemblance.”
<sup>5</sup> p. [322](https://books.google.com/books?id=s1gSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA322#v=onepage&q&f=true)

**References**

Buttmann, Alexander. [*A Grammar of the New Testament Greek.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=s1gSAAAAIAAJ) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry. Andover: Draper, 1873.

Wilke, Christian Gottlob. [*A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry.Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald. Rev. ed. New York: American Book, 1889.

Winer, George Benedikt. [*A Grammar of the Idiom of the New Testament.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IE5CAAAAYAAJ) 7th ed. Andover: Draper, 1892.

Answer (score 0):

If we can use one of the more modern translations, such as  [NIV](http://biblehub.com/niv/2_timothy/1.htm), the meaning becomes clearer:

> I thank God, whom I serve, **as my ancestors did**, with a clear
>   conscience, as night and day I constantly remember you in my prayers.

Although [a majority of scholars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Epistle_to_Timothy#Authorship) state that this epistle was written in Paul's name, not by Paul, the author is crediting Paul with acknowledging his ancestors. [Burton L. Mack says in Who Wrote the New Testament, page 206, that its attribution to Paul is clearly fictional, for its language, style and thought are thoroughly un-Pauline; Bart D. Ehrman cites linguistic evidence of this in "Forged: Writing in the Name of God*,page 98.]

The original Greek text can be read at http://biblehub.com/interlinear/study/2_timothy/1.htm

Comment: "Although we now know that this epistle was written in Paul's name, not by Paul" There's lots of disagreement about that.

Comment: @curiousdannii Of course there is disagreement, and in matters of faith so there should be. But there is little disagreement among scholars.

Comment: @curiousdannii Burton L. Mack says in Who Wrote the New Testament, page 206, that its attribution to Paul is clearly fictional, for its language, style and thought are thoroughly un-Pauline. He says the ‘personal’ references to particular occasions in the lives of Timothy and Paul do not fit with reconstructions of that history taken from the authentic letters of Paul.

Comment: @curiousdannii Bart D. Ehrman writes in "Forged: Writing in the Name of God*,page 98, about the study undertaken on the pastoral epistles (1 and 2 Timothy, and Titus) by A. N. Harrison in 1921. One of his most cited statistics is that there are 848 different words used in the pastoral letters. Of that number 306, or more than one third, do not occur in any of the other Pauline letters of the New Testament. That is an inordinately high number, especially as about two thirds of these 306 words were used by Christian authors living in the second century.

Comment: @curiousdannii Nevertheless, it is my understanding that comments are reserved for requests for clarification or for identifying problems that can not be summarised by "I do not agree." In this and other cases, that seems to be the theme of your comments.

Comment: Do you deny the existence of conservative scholars? To say "there is little disagreement among scholars" is inaccurate, but at least it acknowledges the disagreement, unlike the answer itself. I'm not saying that I disagree, I'm requesting that you edit your answer to change "Although we know ..." to "Many, perhaps even a majority, of scholars believe ..." because as it is now, it is stating as fact something that can never be definitively known and which is currently strongly debated. Thank you for editing it :)

Comment: @curiousdannii In a spirit of cooperation, I have changed this, as you will see above. Incidentally, where we disagree, if we do disagree, is probably on who is a 'scholar' and who is a theologian.

Comment: That's a very condescending statement. And just for example, my NIGTC commentary on the pastorals comes down on the side of pro-Paul, and that's a very scholarly series. But I'd say that the debate over authorship is actually primarily theologically motivated, with Paul's authorship denied by those who want to distance the apostle from the polity of the pastorals. We know Paul often, perhaps usually, used scribes and wrote with coauthors, so vocab has to be the least significant factor for considering authorship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20421/discussion-between-dick-harfield-and-curiousdannii).

Comment: Please cite actual scholars rather than saying 'a majority of scholars' (I can name several myself, but this is part of showing your work). It looks like you have some good data in comments, please integrate it into the answer.

Comment: @Dan I only just saw your request, perhaps obscured because of the migration. It is impractical to list all the scholars 'for' and all the scholars 'against' the view that 2 Tim is pseudepigraphical, although I provided a couple in notes. I have, however, now provided a link to Wikipedia, which says what I said, with its own citations, which I hope meets standards. Incidentally, while I accept the spirit of curiousdannii's disagreement, I feel that other references to "anti-conservative bias of posts " seem inappropriate.

Comment: @DickHarfield I agree with those accusations as being unhelpful. I'd love to see you incorporate your citations of Ehrman and Mack into the post (comments are temporary).

Comment: @kmote please use comments to point out factual issues with the post, vague disagreements such as 'anti-conservative bias' are not constructive.

Comment: @curiousdannii note my edit, that comment was intended for kmote, not you. My apologies for the false ping. I've retained your comments since they are focused on factual issues.

Answer (score -3):

Paul is linking his righteous law keeping as being a continuation of their Jewish religion. This righteousness is not a sinless perfectionism but through the use of the God ordained means of repentance confession washing and sin offering. After using these means the worshipper walks away with a clear conscience because his sin is covered.